# How does the browser reach an IP address?

Tags: web, networking, ip

When I type a domain URL in the browser (or send a ping or write code that fetches a particular IP) the browser gets the associated IP address based on DNS lookup in a distributed database system - the DNS name servers.

But once the IP is obtained - how does the browser know how to go to the particular computer that this IP represents?

```
import urllib.request
nf = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.1.2")
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about how web browsers work.

Comment: It's about networking, I could have asked about sending a ping without a browser or about IP lookup using python code

Comment: If you can [edit] your question to make it a programming question, then please do so.  You would need to add a [mre] (such as python code) that demonstrates what you trying to do and explain what issues you are encountering that cause it not to work.

Comment: I would still vote to close this question because the topic is too broad to cover in a few paragraphs here. A full answer would require many pages or even an entire book. I took an entire college course on how internet routing works.

Comment: I am grateful to StackOverflow that enables me to ask this python programming question and I am grateful to Ronald that taught me, made me a better programmer and deepened my understanding in networking in addition to programming in one short paragraph. Unfortunately for all of us, I stumbled upon @StephenOstermiller who is in violation of Community Guidelines when he abuses the platform by advertising himself and acts as a barrier to teaching and learning. So I flagged his comment and I hope he we will be dealt with by StackOverflow officials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system will compare the target IP address with its own IP address. If both addresses are part of the same network, the OS will issue an ARP request to obtain the physical address (the MAC) of the target interface.

If both IP addresses are not part of the same network, the OS will forward the traffic to the gateway responsible for the subnet that is addressed. If it has no such a route, the OS will forward the traffic to the default gateway.

From there the game starts anew.

Comment: ok so basically the OS looks for the IP in its own network's routing table and if it's not found it goes through the internet gateway to the parent network that holds this origin network to make the same lookup and so it continues with more and more networks - eventually finding the path to the IP if one exists.

Comment: It is not the client computer that does most of the work. If it can't reach the target computer directly, it will send the traffic to its gateway, which will then start the entire procedure anew as if it had to send something itself. This is not visible by the client computer.